# Difficulty solving first order linear PDE, characteristics hard to obtain.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The first order linear PDE I am looking at it is.

$$(\cos(y) + \cos(x+y))z_x-(\cos(x)+\cos(x+y))z_y=0$$

When I try to solve for the characteristics, I obtain the following ODE's.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\cos(x)-\cos(x+y)$$

I'm not really able to decouple the system, even through changing to diagonalized coordinates. Im not sure if I should expect the solutions for the characteristics to even have a closed form expression based on numerical results I get from these ODE's.

Comment: @JackyChong Fixing this now.

Comment: Explore using trig identities like $\cos(2A)+\cos(2B)=2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)$. Cancel common factors first before going to the ODE system. Or create new common factors if simplifications appear possible.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've tried converting to a different coordinate system, say u = x+y and v = x-y, then using trig identities, and it doesn't decouple the system anymore from what I can tell. Both sides will still be of the f(x) + g(x)h(y) where the presence of both terms makes things impossible to decouple, although if only one was present I could decouple the system.

Comment: The coordinate transformation needs to be specific to the PDE, otherwise you indeed do not get any simplification. As usual there is no guarantee for a symbolic solution in a random ODE system. If the task is from a text book then there might be a trick that you can reconstruct, or perhaps also not.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing $\frac{dy}{dt}$ by $\frac{dx}{dt}$ we obtain
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)}{\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)}
$$
$$
\implies [\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)]dx+[\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)]dy=0. \tag{1}
$$
Equation $(1)$ is an exact differential equation, since
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)]=-\sin(x+y)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)]. \tag{2}
$$
There is, therefore, a function $u(x,y)$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\cos(x)+\cos(x+y),\tag{3a} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}&=\cos(y)+\cos(x+y). \tag{3b}
\end{align}
Integrating $(3\text{a})$ we find
$$
u(x,y)=\sin(x)+\sin(x+y)+f(y). \tag{4}
$$
From $(4)$ and $(3\text{b})$ it follows that
$$
\frac{df}{dy}=\cos(y) \implies f(y)=\sin(y) + C. \tag{5}
$$
Equation $(1)$ implies $du=0$, hence $u=$ constant, i.e.
$$
\sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(x+y)=C_1. \tag{6}
$$
The solution to the given PDE is, therefore,
$$
z(x,y)=F(\sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(x+y)), \tag{7}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

Comment: I really overlooked the exact differential idea. This is really slick, thank you.